# How to use Encode::MIME::Header for From header properly?

Tags: perl, utf-8, header, mime

When I use `Encode::MIME::Header` encoding `From:` header, it somehow encodes entire string including header name:

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -MEncode -E 'say encode(MIME_Header => q{From: "児島 新" <shin@kojima.org>});'
=?UTF-8?B?RnJvbTogIuWFkOWztiDmlrAiIDxzaGluQGtvamltYS5vcmc+?=
```

What I expect is:

```
From: "=?UTF-8?B?5YWQ5bO2IOaWsA==?=" <shin@kojima.org>
```

Could someone point me out what's wrong with my code and what should I do.  Is `Encode::MIME::Header` broken?

Here is my `$Encode::VERSION`:

```
$ perl -MEncode -E 'say $Encode::VERSION;'
2.93
```

I'm sure that `Encode::MIME::Header` was not like that before.
The system perl from OSX seems pretty sane for me.

```
$ /usr/bin/perl -Mutf8 -MEncode -E 'say $Encode::VERSION; say encode(MIME_Header => q{From: "児島 新" <shin@kojima.org>});'
2.49
From: "=?UTF-8?B?5YWQ5bO2IOaWsA==?=" <shin@kojima.org>
```

Comment: I've got Perl 5.20.1 on Ubuntu installed via perlbrew with Encode 2.89 and Encode::MIME::Header 2.25, and it encodes the full string too.

Comment: In https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Encode#L279 it talks about being fully compliant to RFC. Maybe that's where it changed? Still looking though.

Comment: So, the author broke backward-compatibility to make it RFC-compliant, maybe? https://github.com/dankogai/p5-encode/issues/105